# How to track an automatic function in VisualBasic

Tags: excel, vba

I´m working with an excel sheet programmed by someone else.
At some point in the worksheet, there is a dated followed by a calendar by the side. Whenever you edit the date, all the cells of the past days until the selected date should be automatically painted by a different color but
The painting of the cells is currently working wrongly, it´s painting the whole calendar

Is there any way of following which part of the code is being executed when I change that date.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It is likely that [there is no code](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Add-change-or-clear-conditional-formats-8a1cc355-b113-41b7-a483-58460332a1af). If there is, you would look for a `Worksheet_Change` handler in the sheet's code module and follow from there.

Comment: Hahaha.. You are funny, Sorry about laughing. Could you please check the `Conditional Formating` in excel sheet. Option is available in `Home Ribbon` >> `Conditional Formatting`